# X11 interaction during image build

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a Dockerfile for an image that requires user interaction during build. I know this is extremely ugly, but there is no easy way around it as it involves installing legacy software using a proprietary installer.

Once built, the container will expose an X11 application over a web socket using `xpra`.

Currently I have it working by creating a volume and doing the installation the first time the container is run. This create a bit of a maintenance problem though, as I would like to ship the pre-built image to a registry.

I am willing to sacrifice the possibility of build automation of the container as it will be rebuilt rarely but deployed often.

Things I have considered:

- Running `xpra` during build. How do I then expose the port so that I can access the web interface?
- Exporting `$DISPLAY` during build. How can I tunnel the X11 traffic over during build?
- Running Xvfb and trying to automate the thing using e.g. xaut. This would be the long term goal, but no easy feat. I am hoping for a quick hack for now.

I realize this is sort of an anti-pattern with Docker, but also a use case where Docker would really shine: Export a legacy application that is a nightmare to set up in an easy-to-use format runnable from a browser.

Comment: read http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/ you can also use https://github.com/marshall/zephyr-docker or Xvfb

Comment: To clarify: I know how to *run* GUI apps. What I need is to interact with a GUI at *build* time.

Comment: https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker

Comment: Same as above, run time

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but I recently encountered the same issue. Since there was no answer posted I'll add mine. I "solved" this by implementing a multi-step build process outlined below.

1. Create a dockerfile to build the base image that installs the tools and dependencies needed to run the installer. For example:

   ```
   # Dockerfile
   FROM centos:6.10
   RUN yum -y install curl glibc.i686 libX11.i686 xorg-x11-utils zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686 \
    && yum clean all
   ```
2. Build the image from the dockerfile and grep for the IMAGE ID.
   NOTE: I'm purposefully NOT namming/tagging this image when building. Since there is no way yet to "un-tag" an image, the intermediate image name:tag would always clutter up the output of "$ docker images".

   ```
   $ docker build . | grep Successfully | cut -d' ' -f3
   ```
3. Run the base image and execute the installer in a container. Also, name the container for easy use later.
   NOTE: because I access my docker host via ssh, I tunnel X11 over ssh with the following run command:

   ```
   $ docker run --name <container_name> --env="DISPLAY" \
   --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" --net=host \
   <IMAGE ID> bash -c "<your commands to curl the installer and execute it>"
   ```

But if you are running docker locally, use the following command instead:

```
    $ docker run --name <container_name> --env="DISPLAY" \
    --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix" \
    <IMAGE ID> bash -c "<your commands to curl the installer and execute it>"
```

4. Create a new image from the container's changes.

   ```
   $ docker commit <container_name> <final-image-name>:<tag>
   $ docker rm <container_name>
   ```
5. Check that the new image tag was created

   ```
   $ docker images | grep <final-image-name>
   ```
6. Run your new image.

   ```
   $ docker run -it --rm <final-image-name>:<tag> bash
   ```
7. Optionally, push the image to a docker registry: dockerhub, artifactory, etc.

   ```
   $ docker login <server>
   $ docker push <final-image-name>:<tag>
   ```